# Creating virtual traps in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a NetLogo model of animals moving around on a landscape.  I'd like to randomly place virtual "camera traps" (field cameras that take photos of animals using a infrared beam) on the landscape at some given distance from each other.  Then when one of the animals walks within some radius of the camera trap, the tick number and information about the animal is recorded.  See below for illustrative example.  Based on the illustration, I'd like to report the tick and animal info for those animals that are intersecting the light blue area surrounding the camera trap (star).  I'm not sure how to do this.  Any suggestions would be really helpful.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just some code to get you started, there are a few ways to do what you need, this is just one of them. In this one there are two breeds, Camera breed (which you might not need to use a breed you can ask a few patches set a variable true to make them camera points and then they can have a record), Camera points record tick and animal which was passing in radius 2 (which you can use distance primitive too)

```
breed [Animals animal]
breed [Cameras Camera]
Cameras-own [records]

to setup
let Zone 2
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  resize-world 0 20 0 20 
  set-patch-size 20
  set-default-shape animals "wolf"
  set-default-shape cameras "star"

create-Cameras 5 [
  set records []
  setxy random max-pxcor random max-pycor 
  set color white 
  ask patches in-radius Zone 
  [
    Set pcolor 88
    ]
  ]
Create-animals 10 [move-to one-of patches]
end



end
to go
ask animals
[
  animals-walk
  ]


tick  
end

to animals-walk
  rt random 10
  fd 1
  if any? cameras in-radius 2 [

    ask one-of cameras in-radius 2 [
      set records lput (list ticks myself) records
    ]]

end
```

[image]

```
  observer> ask camera 4 [ print records]
    [[0 (animal 10)] [0 (animal 11)] [1 (animal 10)] [1 (animal 6)] [2 (animal 10)] 
    [2 (animal 6)] [3 (animal 10)] [3 (animal 6)] [4 (animal 6)] [10 (animal 7)] 
    [11 (animal 7)] [12 (animal 7)] [13 (animal 7)]]
```

Update:
This one does not use a Breed for cameras instead used patches:

```
    breed [Animals animal]

patches-own [records is-camera-point?]
Globals [Cameras]

    to setup
    let Zone 2
      clear-all
      reset-ticks
      resize-world 0 20 0 20 
      set-patch-size 20
      set-default-shape animals "wolf"
     setup-world

    Create-animals 10 [move-to one-of patches]
    end

    to setup-world
    ask patches [
      set pcolor white
      set records []
      set is-camera-point? false
    ]

    ask n-of 5 patches [
      set is-camera-point? true
      set records []

      set pcolor red]

    set Cameras patches with [is-camera-point?]
    end
    to go
    ask animals
    [
      animals-walk
      ]


    tick  
    end

    to animals-walk-with-Radius
      rt random 10
      fd 1
      if any? cameras in-radius 2 [

        ask one-of cameras in-radius 2 [
          set records lput (list ticks myself) records
        ]
        ]

    end
    to animals-walk ; with distance
      rt random 10
      fd 1
      if any? cameras with [distance myself < 2] [

        ask one-of cameras with [distance myself < 2] [
          set records lput (list ticks myself) records
        ]
        ]

    end
```

Comment: @user2359494 can you please provide the full models to me , I would like to extend it please send to my email :) my email : jellyforjully088@yahoo.com   thanks in Advance #look interesting